# Shorter execution of powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Say I have a script to be executed in a single call, how do I do it?

Like, say I have a powershell script saved at `E:\Fldr\scrpt.ps1`. 
Now if I have to normally execute that script is PowerShell ISE then I would have to use:

`& "E:\Fldr\scrpt.ps1"`

and the scrpt.ps1 gets executed.

But whatI want is, when I write a word, say "exeScrpt" instead of `& "E:\Fldr\scrpt.ps1"` then I want scrpt.ps1 to get executed.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you for checking in..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your call to the script in a function:

```
function Invoke-Script
{
    E:\Fldr\scrpt.ps1
}
```

Then you can run your script by executing a single command anywhere after the definition:

```
Invoke-Script
```

Note that it is good practice to name your functions according to the Verb-Noun [cmdlet naming standard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878270(v=vs.85).aspx), so something like `Invoke-Script` instead of `exeScrpt`.  If you really want a single word as the name, then you can additionally create an [alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-alias?view=powershell-6) for your function:

```
New-Alias -Name exeScrpt -Value Invoke-Script
```